# How would I write this split with php instead of javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I was manipulating a string with javascript to split numbers that i need in a pattern like this :

```
150952-0535
```

generated from a number like this :

```
15095205350008
```

The javascript is like this and it does the trick :

```
var s7img = '15095205350008';
s7img = '<img src="http://site.com/images/' 
          + s7img.substring(0, 6) + "-0" 
          + s7img.substring(7, s7img.length - 4)
          + '?$product_stamp$">';
```

How could I accomplish the same thing just using php?  I started poking around with something like :

```
$sku = "15095205350008";
$s7img = substr($sku, 0,6);
```

But I am not sure...

Comment: You're on the right track. Just keep working it ([`strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) will help).

Comment: Thanks.. almost had it then Switz game me the answer :)  Thanks for the edit too.

Comment: You're really better off working these kinds of things out on your own, since you won't get good at it until you really understand what's going on and do it in practice for a while.

Comment: Yea.. it was glitched because of something else I screwed up, so starting to doubt myself I thought "Stack Overflow!"  Half the time it seems a few minutes after I ask a question I figure out the answer =P

Comment: I've asked 11 questions, but I've almost submitted another 10-15. As I'm describing the problem, I figure out what I need to do and don't need the question anymore. See: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/02/how-to-write-without-writing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$s7img = "<img src='http://site.com/images/'".substr($sku, 0, 6)."-0".substr($sku, 7, -4);
```

According to your javascript.